# What location do I put for chrome executable for webOS simulator?

Tags: visual-studio-code, webos

I've tried all common locations for macOS for google `/Applications/Google...` and I can't seem to get any path to work. Is there a specific way to put it to make it recognize the path? I want to use a webOS simulator for a Samsung TV app.

I've tried these:

```
~/Library/Application\ Support/Google/Chrome.app
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google\ Chrome
```

I've tried everything here. What do I put?

[image]